# Lots of custom JS events through body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

So I've started using custom events heavily in the app I'm writing and find myself binding them all to the **body** tag.  Personally I'd rather not have to bind to any tag at all for custom events.

Am I doing something wrong (I get the feeling I am)?  Also is there any harm in binding and triggering lots of events through the **body** tag?

I'm using jQuery [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: What are you wanting to trigger the events?  Time based or???

Comment: @Jared, there are 2 scenarios, one is based off a click, another is at the end of an ajax response, in both cases the idea is to notify a number of objects to take action on the portion of the DOM they are managing.  Also, I have a number of objects which are managing markup that has been removed from the DOM, my hand-rolled tab code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [jQuery pub/sub plugin by Peter Higgins](https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js)
really small and simple, and you don't bind actual events to the body

Comment: Neat, I'd wondered if there was a way to work with events without binding to DOM elements at all, I'll have a peak at this plugin and let you know what I think.

Comment: Hmm, it certainly is a small piece of code and that's nice.  What I don't like about it though is 'events' are now synchronous.  One aspect I like about the DOM-driven events is the ability for them to be asynchronous.  I'm actually gutting out code similar to what's in this plugin right now :)

Comment: when you say synchronous you refer to the way they are being fired? because i'm sure that if you check the jQuery source you will see that a similar list is held for handling the events, maybe there is a setTimeout(functionToFire,0); to let the event loop continue with it's work and then fire these events

Comment: and if you do have improvements - fork it and contribute the change or publish it -i'm sure more devs will benefit from it

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Avi, it's not the exact answer I was looking for, but has lead me to realize the answer.  I had too much to put in a comment so I put my own answer up, but gave you an upvote in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick test I've discovered [custom events in jQuery aren't even asynchronous](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6959), that is disappointing to say the least.

I would expect if I have to 'bind' to an element jQuery would delegate to the DOM to fire an event, but perhaps the DOM will only fire events that are part of the engine, which begs the question, why would jQuery ever ask you to bind custom events to DOM elements in the first place, it just seems silly.

My hope was that jQuery was delegating to the DOM under the hood and we'd be avoiding userspace code like what we find in pubsub (it's probly slower than engine code and linearizes event firing), but it seems the DOM doesn't provide such a mechanism (at least I doubt it if jQuery isn't taking advantage w/ it's custom event implementation).

Well it gives merit to the pubsub plugin, but I'm disappointed on both levels now.  I'd hazard a guess this means there's no harm in 'binding' a ton of events to one DOM element, since you're just building up an array inside of jQuery.  The worst case is we have a very large array of registered events that has to be linearly traversed every time a custom event is fired.  >Reminded of event implementations inside of PHP..<

Comment: [Further experimentation](http://pastebin.com/rqn0FZDu) has lead to the discovery that native custom events aren't even asynchronous, weird, clearly I'm missing something, lol.